# How to remove submit button and save image as well as show image using ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi guys i want to remove the submit button and upload my image with only upload button .also i am using ajax to send the image to the database as well as in th eupload folder. when i remove the submit button and use $(this).submit() in my form it shows nothing and no ajax runs.
What am i doing wrong?
here is my code

```
        {
            if(!$timeline_image=="")
            {
                $image_properties = array('src' => base_url("uploads/".$timeline_image),'width' => '900px','height'=> '400px','id'=>'coverimg', 'title' => 'That was quite a night','rel'   => 'lightbox');
                echo img($image_properties);
            }else{
                $timiline_image = array(
                    'src'   => base_url("assets/img/Facebook-cover.jpg"),
                    'width' => '900px',
                    'height'=> '400px',

                );

                echo img($timiline_image);
            }
            ?>
            <div id="timelineselector" class="col-md-3 grow">
                <?php echo form_open_multipart('',["id"=>"form_cover"]); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ;?>">
                <?php echo form_upload(["name"=>"timelineimage","id"=>"timelineimage" ]); ?>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now for ajax

```
    jQuery('#form_cover').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var url = '<?php echo base_url("user/coverimage"); ?>';
  formData.value
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#coverimg').attr('src', data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      //error function
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) is an event binder which binds the function you pass to it with a submit event of the desired element.

In order to perform your action as desired, you must replace the `submit` listener with an on `change` listener targeted at the upload field. Since after the removal of the submit button, the submit action doesn't occur.

```
$('#timelineimage').change(function(e){
     // Logic
});
```

Comment: how would i pass the form data then? @Tariq B

Comment: its showing me an error "TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor does not implement interface HTMLFormElement."

Comment: You may try   `var form = jQuery('#form_cover')[0]);` or `var form = document.getElementById('form_cover'); and then pass it to `FormData`.

Comment: now the ajax calls but i can't open the browse upload it just submit an empty image!!@Tariq B

Comment: Change the .click event to .change and it should work fine.